# How to download entire Youtube playlist videos without installing any software?

Tags: video, download, youtube, playlists

Installing a software puts a restriction that you need admin priviledge, which is not possible all the times, hence is there an online solution to download entire youtube playlists?

Answer (score 6):

There are two online solutions to download entire videos fro youtube.
Method 1) From collectyoutube.com :  Steps are as follows

Copy and paste the playlist link to the first input box of the site and hit "Go". It will display all the videos of the playlist. To download all videos at once, just hit "Download" which will begin the download instantly. In order to download it via IDM, choose the mode as "Download IDM" and hit download. It will download one file containing links which can be imported to any download manager like IDM to schedule downloads later.

Method 2) From youtubemultidownloader.com : Steps are as follows:

Choose the playlist from tabs and paste the youtube playlist link to the input bx provided and hit the button. It will start showing the videos of that playlist. In order to simultaneously download all videos, just copy all the links provided in the textbox to the clipboad and import it in the IDM or any download manager to begin download or schedule it later.

Comment: "`There are two online solutions to download entire videos fro youtube`"... There's another solution I've used.... Go to http://en.savefrom.net/, paste in the YouTube video URL, press the little check mark, then press the **download video in browser** option, and BAM, you get an MP4 file that starts downloading with the YT video.

Comment: collectyoutube.com does not exist